# Motorcycle dragging when not in neutral

Tags: transmission, clutch, gears

I have a cbr250r, 2 years old. when I try to move the motorcycle physically it feels a lot heavier/dragging than doing it in neutral.
Does it has to do something with clutch? as my gear shifts also feels dry and hard. they take in lot effort to shift in at any gear. I tried to improve the slack on the clutch lever. Felt better for a few days and then again back to normal hard shifts. the motorcycle doesn't also have many kilometers and has gone for servicing at every mentioned interval.

Also it is making squeaking noise from front tyres at slow speeds feels like maybe pads are sticking with the disk. Would that be the cause for drag, I am not sure as I think the pads would have already settled in.
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: The clutch is a different system to the brakes. Is your gearbox seizing? Are the brakes set up correctly? Has this been serviced properly in this 2 years?

Comment: If the front wheel isn't rotating freely that will make no difference to whether it is in gear or in neutral when you push it. Seems like the clutch isn't fully disengaging - you need *less* slack on the clutch lever. But why do you want to push the vehicle when it is in gear? If the clutch is a 'wet' clutch (in an oil bath) there will always be more drag than when in neutral.

Comment: @Solar Mike yup, I have been bringing the vehicle to service at all intervals. I thought maybe clutch drag or something. Is there a DIY thing I can do to separate the pads? I checked just now and seems like the are quite stick to the disk. Even when squeezing brake lever doesn't move the pads closes.

Comment: @weather Vane, I thought that maybe gears are hard so I increased the slack, Do I need to reduce the slack?

Comment: If there is too much slack, the clutch might not fully disengage. If there isn't enough, it might slip. If it is hard to change gear while riding, and hard to push when in gear, that suggests the clutch is not fully disengaging.

Comment: So I need to reduce the freeplay and I should be good on the gears and it would be easier to push? as with full clutch pressed ad in gear its heavier to push than in neutral.

Comment: As I wrote, it will likely be always heavier to push when in gear. The clutch is between the engine and the gearbox (not between the gearbox and the rear wheel) so at the least you'll be rotating the gears. You might like to ask your service centre to adjust the clutch.